# CASE with CHARINDEX and CONVERT

Tags: sql-server, cast

I have a column of characters in SQL Server 2014 that I have to convert to numeric and give them the opposite value (- to + and + to -).
The data looks like this:

```
 -0000000000002999                                                                   
000000000000002999
000000000000002459
 -0000000000002459
000000000000000437
```

I need it to look like this:

```
29.99
-29.99
-24.59
24.59
-4.37
```

This is the query i'm trying to use but it makes them all positive!
select

```
CASE
  WHEN CHARINDEX('-', o.PMT_AMOUNT) > '0'
     THEN CONVERT(numeric(18), Right(o.PMT_AMOUNT,17))* -.01 
  ELSE CONVERT(numeric(18), (o.PMT_AMOUNT)) * .01 
END from OPS_PMT_RECON_CONV o
```

Comment: Why `> '0'` instead of `> 0`? Zero is not a string. Why are you storing these numbers as strings in the first place? What is the data type of `PMT_AMOUNT`?

Comment: just the way I had it. I changed it but it makes now difference to outcome

Comment: Just so you're aware of how the SE network works, if you find an answer helpful, click the up arrow. If an answer resolves your issue, click the outline of a green checkmark.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more concise way to write this query without conditionals ([SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d7092/1), but I guessed on the data type):

```
SELECT 
  PMT_AMOUNT = -1 * CONVERT(NUMERIC(20,2), STUFF(o.PMT_AMOUNT,LEN(o.PMT_AMOUNT)-1,0,'.'))
FROM dbo.OPS_PMT_RECON_CONV AS o;
```

Or even simpler, as @ypercube suggests:

```
SELECT 
  PMT_AMOUNT = -0.01 * CONVERT(NUMERIC(20,2), o.PMT_AMOUNT)
FROM dbo.OPS_PMT_RECON_CONV AS o;
```

A couple of suggestions:

- [Store the *number* in the database, instead of this awkward string representation](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type). What is the point of persisting the number this way, even if you can't control how it comes to you? Converting to a number *first*, and storing it that way, will prevent you from storing junk in your database and end users getting burned for it.
- Specify *both precision and scale* when defining `numeric`. [This post is primarily about `varchar`, but applies equally to other types that accept parameters](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).
- [Always specify the schema](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).
- [Always terminate statements with semi-colons](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am pretty new to SQL so I know that some of my code is quite cumbersome

Answer (score 1):

Don't over think the problem.

There is a MONEY datatype in MSSQL that is excellent in parsing strings during conversion.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test( PMT_AMOUNT varchar(512) not null ) 

INSERT INTO #Test
values
    (' -0000000000002999'),
    ('000000000000002999'),
    ('000000000000002459'),
    (' -0000000000002459'),
    ('000000000000000437')

SELECT 
    convert( money , PMT_AMOUNT ) / 100 
    , -1 * ( convert( money , PMT_AMOUNT ) / 100 ) 
FROM #Test

drop TABLE #Test
```

Comment: What does MONEY do here that NUMERIC doesn't? (Also you may have missed the part of the requirement that the sign be changed.)

Comment: It appears to me from quite some experience in the financial field, that the internal parsing that MS-SQL does from character to money datatype is more robust than to the numeric datatype. Once it is in a Money type, it can be cast to numeric or decimal more easily.

Comment: Can you show some actual examples where a string is converted "more robustly" to MONEY than to NUMERIC? And what do you do if your numeric value needs more than 4 decimal places?

Comment: I can't seem to find the SQL examples from a Philly SQL Server user group meeting, but certainly handling commas and currency signs don't work except in the money datatype. And yes I missed the sign flipping.

Answer (score 0):

I had to multiply both by -

CASE

```
  WHEN CHARINDEX('-', o.PMT_AMOUNT) > '0'
    THEN CONVERT(numeric(18), Right(o.PMT_AMOUNT,17)) * -.01 
  ELSE CONVERT(numeric(18), (o.PMT_AMOUNT)) * -.01 
  end from OPS_PMT_RECON_CONV o
```

Comment: So what purpose does the `CASE` expression serve?

Comment: @ypercube But is that differentiation *needed*? Not for me. Perhaps there is an edge case we haven't been told about.